# Understanding Scala code with flatmap and function

Tags: scala

I am preparing for a test by looking at old exams for my course. For one of the problems, we have to show what the result is for the given code.

```
val primes4 = List(2, 3, 5, 7)
def foo(num:Int) = num > 1 && ((2 to num-1 toList) forall (x => num % x != 0))
val result = primes4.flatMap(x => x :: (x to x+1 toList).filter(x => !foo(x)))
```

The answer that is given for the problem says the result should look like this

> result: List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

I thought I understood the code until I saw that 7 is included in the list. I don't know why 7 is included when we look at it the following way

with 7 we get

7::7,8

7>1 is true

forall (2,3,4,5,6) num% x != 0 this is true

so TRUE && TRUE evaluate to TRUE so x => !foo(x) should evaluate to false. I thought if this is false then why is 7 included? Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or is the answer simply wrong?

If you could list out step by step what happens this would be the optimal solution.

Comment: `x :: (x to x+1 toList).filter(x => !foo(x))` –– this prepends `x` to the result of the `.filter`, so, when `x=7`, it will be included regardless of what `foo` is doing.

Comment: @Dima If you would like to post this as an answer I can choose it

Comment: `foo` just checks whether a number is prime. `result` just takes the four primes, and for each of those primes `x`, inserts `x + 1` if it's non-prime. I.e. it inserts the next number after each prime except 2. Thus, the answer must be `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`, because 4, 6, 8 follow 3, 5, 7 respectively. This code makes no sense; It looks like it has been invented purely for torturing poor students with incomprehensible nonsensical code.